# What are the best resources on image synthesis?

Tags: references, image-processing, computer-vision, generative-models

What are some good resources to learn about image synthesis? What are some of the key concepts or architectures to study?

I understand image synthesis as generating new images with ML techniques.

Answer (score 2):

This is a book on Generative Models:

> Tomczak, Jakub M. "[Deep Generative Modeling](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-93158-2_8)". 2022.

To help readers to choose which models to study I summarize the main classes of Generative Models and provide a brief description of each, which are the resources I studied for an introductory course to Generative Models

## AutoRegressive Models

The image is modeled as a sequence of pixel values. The image distribution $p(x)$ is factorized into a product of conditional distributions and the generation is an autoregressive prediction of the next pixel values based on the previous ones.

### Relevant papers

> Van Den Oord, Aäron, Nal Kalchbrenner, and Koray Kavukcuoglu. "Pixel recurrent neural networks." International conference on machine learning. PMLR, 2016.
>
> Chen, Xi, et al. "Pixelsnail: An improved autoregressive generative model." International Conference on Machine Learning. PMLR, 2018.
>
> Menick, Jacob, and Nal Kalchbrenner. "Generating high fidelity images with subscale pixel networks and multidimensional upscaling." ICLR (2019)

### Pros

- Simple
- Exact likelihood, allow sampling from the distribution

### Cons

- Does not have a learned representation
- Inference is slow, because of the sequential nature

## Normalizing Flows

Parameterizes $p(x)$ as an invertible deterministic transformation from a base density, such as a standard Gaussian

### Relevant papers

> Dinh, Laurent, David Krueger, and Yoshua Bengio. ”NICE: Non-linear independent components estimation." ICLR 2015 workshop
>
> Dinh, Laurent, Jascha Sohl-Dickstein, and Samy Bengio. "Density estimation using Real NVP." ICLR 2017
>
> Kingma, Durk P., and Prafulla Dhariwal. "Glow: Generative flow with invertible 1x1 convolutions." Advances in neural information
> processing systems 31 (2018)
>
> Papamakarios, George, et al. "Normalizing Flows for Probabilistic Modeling and Inference." J. Mach. Learn. Res. 22.57 (2021): 1-64.
>
> Kobyzev, Ivan, Simon JD Prince, and Marcus A. Brubaker. "Normalizing flows: An introduction and review of current methods." IEEE
> Transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence 43.11
> (2020): 3964-3979.

### Pros

- A very flexible and elegant formulation with exact likelihood
- Allows fast sempling
- Provides a latent representation

### Cons

- Limited freedom in the choice of the architecture, for theoretical (invertibility) and computational constraints
- Latent space needs to have the same dimensionality as the output for invertibility

## Latent Variable Models

Use an encoder network to map inputs onto a low-dimensional latent space and a decoder network to generate images from a latent code

### Relevant papers

> Kingma, Diederik P., and Max Welling. "Auto-encoding variational bayes." arXiv preprint arXiv:1312.6114 (2013).
>
> Doersch, Carl. "Tutorial on variational autoencoders." arXiv preprint arXiv:1606.05908 (2016).
>
> Kingma, Diederik P., and Max Welling. "An introduction to variational autoencoders." Foundations and Trends® in Machine Learning 12.4
> (2019): 307-392.
>
> Higgins et al, $\beta$-vae: Learning Basic Visual Concepts with a Constrained Variational Framework, ICLR 2017
>
> Van Den Oord et al "Neural discrete representation learning." Neurips (2017).

### Pros

- No architecture constraint
- Efficient to learn, flexible
- Allows sampling

### Cons

- Does not have exact likelihood
- Blurry samples if wrongly tuned and without perceptual components in loss

## Generative Adversarial Networks

Train two networks, a generator which produces synthetic data and a discriminator which distinguishes between synthetic and real data

### Relevant papers

> Goodfellow, Ian et al. Generative Adversarial Networks, NIPS’14
>
> Goodfellow, Ian. Tutorial: Generative Adversarial Networks, NIPS’16
>
> M .Mirza and S. Osindero, "Conditional generative adversarial nets." arXiv preprint arXiv:1411.1784 (2014)
>
> Salimans, Tim, et al. "Improved techniques for training GANs." Advances in neural information processing systems 29 (2016).
>
> Zhu, Jun-Yan, et al. "Unpaired image-to-image translation using cycle-consistent adversarial networks." Proceedings of the IEEE international conference on computer vision. 2017.
>
> Isola, Phillip, et al. "Image-to-image translation with conditional adversarial networks." Proceedings of the IEEE conference on computer vision and pattern recognition. 2017
>
> Jolicoeur-Martineau, Alexia. "The relativistic discriminator: a key element missing from standard GAN." arXiv preprint arXiv:1807.00734 ICLR (2018).
>
> W. Fedus, et al., Many Paths To Equilibrium: Gans Do Not Need To Decrease A Divergence At Every Step, ICLR’18
>
> Schmidhuber, Jürgen. "Generative adversarial networks are special cases of artificial curiosity (1990) and also closely related to predictability minimization (1991)." Neural Networks 127 (2020): 58-66

### Pros

- Sharp, higher resolution outputs compared to the previous classes
- Full freedom in architecture
- Fast sampling
- Latent representation

### Cons

- No likelihood
- Training instability

## Diffusion Models

Learn a denoising process which transforms random noise into an image

### Relevant Papers

> Sohl-Dickstein, Jascha, et al. "Deep unsupervised learning using nonequilibrium thermodynamics." International Conference on Machine Learning. PMLR, 2015.
>
> Ho, Jonathan, Ajay Jain, and Pieter Abbeel. "Denoising diffusion probabilistic models." Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 33 (2020): 6840-6851.
>
> Nichol, Alexander Quinn, and Prafulla Dhariwal. "Improved denoising diffusion probabilistic models." International Conference on Machine
> Learning. PMLR, 2021.
>
> Ho, Jonathan, et al. "Cascaded Diffusion Models for High Fidelity Image Generation." J. Mach. Learn. Res. 23 (2022): 47-1.
>
> Song, Yang, et al. "Consistency models." arXiv preprint arXiv:2303.01469 (2023).

### Pros

- Stable training
- Great tractability/flexibility trade-off
- High quality samples

### Cons

- Lower likelihood value (even with higher quality results)
- Slow to sample from (Consistency models is an emergent class which aims to alleviate that)

## Text-to-Image generation

Finally, the section where all the hype is, with the previous model classes applied to text-to-image generation

> Zhang, Han, et al. "Stackgan: Text to photo-realistic image synthesis with stacked generative adversarial networks." Proceedings of the IEEE international conference on computer vision. 2017.
>
> Esser, Patrick, Robin Rombach, and Bjorn Ommer. "Taming transformers for high-resolution image synthesis." Proceedings of the IEEE/CVF conference on computer vision and pattern recognition. 2021.
>
> Ramesh, Aditya, et al. "Hierarchical text-conditional image generation with clip latents." arXiv preprint arXiv:2204.06125 (2022).
>
> Saharia, Chitwan, et al. "Photorealistic text-to-image diffusion models with deep language understanding." Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 35 (2022): 36479-36494.
>
> Rombach, Robin, et al. "High-resolution image synthesis with latent diffusion models." Proceedings of the IEEE/CVF Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition. 2022.

Comment: Great, thanks :D. What do you think is relevant for practitioners in 2023? Is knowledge about autoregressive models and normalizing flows relevant in practice? Or rather much more focus should be put on the other approaches you've mentioned?

Comment: I feel that AR models could have some importance, for example in Taming Transformers for high-resolution image synthesis they used a AR model based on transformers, and parts of it actually made into LDM which is at the base of Stable Diffusion. There are also other works which try to use transformers and obtain similar results to Diffusion approaches, so it could be useful. I also personally did not focus on Normalizing Flows, so they may not be so relevant for now, but it's a personal opinion.

Comment: There are also Energy Based model, currently not included in the answer, but I'm planning to update and include them

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you are looking for but, my preferred resource is the book by Rafael C. Gonzalez and Richard E. Woods titled *Digital Image Processing*, Pearson, and now in its fourth edition. It's a quite comprehensive text on image processing, it covers: spatial filtering, filtering in the frequency domain, image restoration, colour image processing, wavelets, etc. The book has twelve chapters and the last chapter covers ML methods for image classification, e.g. NNets and Deep Learning.

Comment: @RichardHardy You are right I guess, I forgot about it.

Comment: Ah @RichardHardy I remember now why didn’t add the ‘adf’ tag: it was because the OP didn’t mention the augmented version of the DF test!

Comment: The DF test is conceptually very similar to the ADF test. We do not need two separate tags for them, so I think we can safely use the ADF tag for both – just like we use the ARIMA tag for both ARMA and ARIMA models.